# Mapped values in SQL PLUS or SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column that contains integers. Those integers refer to a C enum.

It would be great to be able to map the numbers to the enum in SQL Plus and/or SQL Developer.

I think I need to use the column command, but haven't figured out exactly how.

For example, if I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
```

I would get something like this:

| name | department |
| --- | --- |
| john doe | 2 |
| jane doe | 5 |

Then in some cpp file I would see that 2 is sales, 5 is support, etc.

It would be great to be able execute some command at the beginning of my session, so when I do the query I get this instead:

| name | department |
| --- | --- |
| john doe | sales |
| jane doe | support |

Comment: Why is the enumeration in a cpp file? Is it part of larger code? Depending on how exactly that enumeration exists on your system, it may be possible to define an external table and use it in the same way as the additional table created in the database in Littlefoot's answer. (Assuming for some reason you are not able or willing to keep that additional data in the database, which is the natural solution.)

Comment: Most of the time I work with non-production databases, so I can add the table. I was just looking for some type of mapping without having to modify the SQL queries or creating views. But I guess there is no alternative. As for why it is an enum in a cpp file? I don't know the answer to that, but suppose it can't change.

Comment: "Why in a cpp file" was more about "what else is in the file". If the file just has a cpp extension but it only has the enumeration defined in it (with, perhaps, some other boilerplate code which can be easily ignored), that would make it easy to turn it into an external table. Which is: In the DB, you make the file available, you describe its structure, and then queries can read data directly from it. Instead of an actual table, you will have an "external table definition" in the db, and the rest in your cpp file (simply treated as a text file).

Comment: Arguably *"2 is sales, 5 is support, etc"* is the entire point of databases, so I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve with "some command at the beginning of my session". If you select a department number from a table, then that department number is what the database is required to return to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it exists in Oracle. What we usually do is to join two (normalized) tables, possibly referenced to each other via foreign key constraints. If I'm wrong and *enum* actually exists, I'd like to see it.

Therefore: sample tables:

```
SQL> create table employees as
  2  select 'john doe' name, 2 department from dual union all
  3  select 'jane doe', 5 from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table departments as
  2  select 2 department, 'sales' name from dual union all
  3  select 5, 'support' from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select * From employees;

NAME     DEPARTMENT
-------- ----------
john doe          2
jane doe          5

SQL> select * from departments;

DEPARTMENT NAME
---------- -------
         2 sales
         5 support
```

This is what we *normally* do:

```
SQL> select e.name, d.name department
  2  from employees e join departments d on d.department = e.department;

NAME     DEPARTM
-------- -------
john doe sales
jane doe support
```

If you're lazy (and don't want to type it every time), create a **view** and then select from the view:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_employees as
  2  select e.name, d.name department
  3  from employees e join departments d on d.department = e.department;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_employees;

NAME     DEPARTM
-------- -------
john doe sales
jane doe support

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution makes sense, but I've found an invisible virtual column to be enough for me to see the mapping when debugging without too much disruption or more complicated queries or views.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an invisible virtual column.

I created a little program that loops through the enum an generates the SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD departmentLbl INVISIBLE AS CASE
WHEN department = 2 THEN 'sales'
WHEN department = 5 THEN 'support'
ELSE TO_CHAR(department)
```

I still need to toggle the visibility back and forth because SQL Developer won't show invisible columns.

Comment: Yep, that's a possibility. I don't like such hidden relations, though. Of course you can hide departments, companies, countries, cities, whatever in some invisible columns in some other tables, but whoever looks at your database will have a hard time understanding this. And once you want to add something, like departments belonging to companies, a boss, a room or some inventory belonging to a department, etc. How will you do that? I prefer Littlefoot's solution over yours by far. At last an RDBMS is made for modeling relations in tables, so why not use it thus?

Comment: Definitively, in this case is more for debugging. I can't or won't change how the system is modeled. I was just looking for an easier way to map the numbers to their labels. Thanks for the feedback.